# Increment indicator column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I have below data, and I am trying to create a indicator column to keep a track of increment in the value by id.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4),
         rank=c(1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3),dates=c('2019-06-15','2019-07-15','2019-08-15','2019-09-15','2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
                 '2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
                 '2019-11-15','2019-12-15','2019-12-15'),new_col=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0)
         )
```

The order of the date matters here.

```
setDT(df)[order(id,dates),]
```

Desired Output

```
   id  rank   dates     new_col
1   1    1   2019-06-15       0
2   1    2   2019-07-15       1
3   1    3   2019-08-15       1
4   1    1   2019-09-15       1
5   1    1   2019-10-15       1
6   1    1   2019-11-15       1
7   1    2   2019-12-15       1
8   2    2   2019-10-15       0
9   2    3   2019-11-15       1
10  2    1   2019-12-15       1
11  3    1   2019-11-15       0
12  3    2   2019-12-15       1
13  4    3   2019-12-15       0
```

Updated input data-

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5),
             rank=c(1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,1),dates=c('2019-06-15','2019-07-10','2019-08-15','2019-09-15','2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
                     '2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
                     '2019-11-15','2019-12-15','2019-12-15','2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15'))
```

Updated Output-

```
      id   rank  dates       new

 1     1     1 2019-06-15     0
 2     1     2 2019-07-10     1
 3     1     3 2019-08-15     1
 4     1     1 2019-09-15     1
 5     1     1 2019-10-15     1
 6     1     1 2019-11-15     1
 7     1     2 2019-12-15     1
 8     2     2 2019-10-15     0
 9     2     3 2019-11-15     1
10     2     1 2019-12-15     1
11     3     1 2019-11-15     0
12     3     2 2019-12-15     1
13     4     3 2019-12-15     0
14     5     1 2019-10-15     0
15     5     1 2019-11-15     0
16     5     1 2019-12-15     0
```

Comment: That is, the first row for each `id` should be `0` and all other values in column `new_col` should be `1` irrespective of the values in columns `rank` and `dates`, is that correct?

Comment: @RushabhPatel Not clear why 14 and 15th are both 0.  there is a date change from 2019-11-15 to 2019-12-15

Comment: @akrun I apologize it was typo. I updated it

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: if markus's interpretation is correct, you can use `setDT(df)[, new := replace(rep(1L, .N), rleid(rank)==1L, 0L), id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use  `diff` on the 'dates' after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%       
   mutate(new = c(0, diff(as.Date(dates)) > 0))
# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   id [4]
#      id  rank dates      new_col   new
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1 2019-06-15       0     0
# 2     1     2 2019-07-15       1     1
# 3     1     3 2019-08-15       1     1
# 4     1     1 2019-09-15       1     1
# 5     1     1 2019-10-15       1     1
# 6     1     1 2019-11-15       1     1
# 7     1     2 2019-12-15       1     1
# 8     2     2 2019-10-15       0     0
# 9     2     3 2019-11-15       1     1
#10     2     1 2019-12-15       1     1
#11     3     1 2019-11-15       0     0
#12     3     2 2019-12-15       1     1
#13     4     3 2019-12-15       0     0
```

#### Update

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(new = +(c(FALSE, diff(as.Date(dates)) > 0) & 
       (any(rank  != lag(rank, default = first(rank))))))
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   id [5]
#      id  rank dates        new
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      <int>
# 1     1     1 2019-06-15     0
# 2     1     2 2019-07-10     1
# 3     1     3 2019-08-15     1
# 4     1     1 2019-09-15     1
# 5     1     1 2019-10-15     1
# 6     1     1 2019-11-15     1
# 7     1     2 2019-12-15     1
# 8     2     2 2019-10-15     0
# 9     2     3 2019-11-15     1
#10     2     1 2019-12-15     1
#11     3     1 2019-11-15     0
#12     3     2 2019-12-15     1
#13     4     3 2019-12-15     0
#14     5     1 2019-10-15     0
#15     5     1 2019-11-15     0
#16     5     1 2019-12-15     0
```

Comment: This assumes that all dates are separated by 1 day. Is that the case?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  It is an update code.  I didn't initially had the  logical vector

Comment: @akrun It should be based on rank. Your code fails for updated sample data.

Comment: @akrun Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rep` and also arrange the dates, as you said they were important:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df %>%
  arrange(id, dates) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new_col2 = c(0, rep(1, (n() - 1))))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>       id  rank dates      new_col new_col2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1     1 2019-06-15       0        0
#>  2     1     2 2019-07-15       1        1
#>  3     1     3 2019-08-15       1        1
#>  4     1     1 2019-09-15       1        1
#>  5     1     1 2019-10-15       1        1
#>  6     1     1 2019-11-15       1        1
#>  7     1     2 2019-12-15       1        1
#>  8     2     2 2019-10-15       0        0
#>  9     2     3 2019-11-15       1        1
#> 10     2     1 2019-12-15       1        1
#> 11     3     1 2019-11-15       0        0
#> 12     3     2 2019-12-15       1        1
#> 13     4     3 2019-12-15       0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is sorted the way you want it, here is a solution using base R:

```
df$new_col_2 = c(0, 1 - diff(df$id))

> df
   id rank      dates new_col new_col_2
1   1    1 2019-06-15       0         0
2   1    2 2019-07-15       1         1
3   1    3 2019-08-15       1         1
4   1    1 2019-09-15       1         1
5   1    1 2019-10-15       1         1
6   1    1 2019-11-15       1         1
7   1    2 2019-12-15       1         1
8   2    2 2019-10-15       0         0
9   2    3 2019-11-15       1         1
10  2    1 2019-12-15       1         1
11  3    1 2019-11-15       0         0
12  3    2 2019-12-15       1         1
13  4    3 2019-12-15       0         0
```